# How do I make my images not go away in HTML after I restart the server

Tags: html, markup

I have these photos that I uploaded to google photos that I use in my html code for my website. They're always there for the day, but then the next day when I reopen up my port all the images on the website are not there anymore and I have to relink them?

```
        <img class="center-image" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ABLVV87ZuT2hZq-urm4ePfrzPpmrwoAIMDrS3159Y6UpbinUCHpxKreWt-2h0x-q7F1-nqrA2TJgROgwqzbGDcgfcGamjsPNJ_kfOMadvO97KxM1FR0FMmQ8SR2CRgJ20ybBpWgBuldFF8w7nEDe6sIgTI-Ax45PSVcP008DbTObcmqtFI-CTFpeixLUA_95MXeyuOT6ZPIpXhvac_jzxRPoGIXzuAFQZnYwHSlWu3zA14VGMfrBia0gNvXke2tv-PJs-0CPKSZxgYfyEBhu6RagolBgfN1E6rl7fgA_KuPXzkXh1fA3jccuU9WAygv8e2eQpwaq8Z1zk_SZSIKviLZ_OU_UB9GGx1W5yU7lMOinuRZfNhHm0fPsz0yn-On5Nf-6C-LAKVvLDmIgbqY9ZM7A7jrcOnnEqzjf2kxNXUoLRH0KQsC1_qAEljL0W_9Yjx_4imJYXRFdtdfR77KpBUhtbHwNR4YP7VJGBrGSdGYyD63ca64Phk_ZOx4n1PYib0Jbusr_FE7fy2NcsdZYa40t-b2VxyRHbSDyEfF5r_P49hG-6nKC0XtbzMCdlJNO5PWOvysMAuxsrN3VHfPp_C2y8Jo9aZPZs83In2SQ57BcuURUoeCLfcSByDaKCRciXaTR1n6JmzdIUMCxHn8MeP0g-TSGxO6xr0_Q_Jd1u56pRgpFH5-zx0frOphzdTqY_j7Ed7zO5frGJd0wAR112yIgkekYWxdAFZqE4issjV6S7Ravdzx9LsTGtM_dPKDxC2iF-dQjiQ-9Kjd-EyZCGlnPlX1qK7vimBncqOcyq4exi7jcMtLOsG5Zi7r8GIb-mPSG2XZhFq43Yz_gK1CFUBnWJ3pxtgi48WLvS9Imb3oatp7OR0s3MqrhgyntyNfpNrDF_QRNVszZIco4nym8DqYyNd4xKp2r19S-5iwgwMLs=w1080-h1080-s-no-gm?authuser=0" alt="Centered Image">
```

Sorry for the long link but it looks smth liek this.

Comment: They are likely short lived links. Store them on your web server

Comment: Ohh, I see! How would I do that? I'm looking this up and i'm not really sure lol, sorry its my first time doing this.